# Navbar text does not appear on mobile version

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

When I open the website on mobile, and then click on the navbar icon, the navbar submenus does not appear. There is a white space. Even if I change the color of the text on the website, it does not change yet.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHCMP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opAlc.png)

I change the text color and excepted to appear the submenus on the white background of the navbar